# How to upgrade and downgrade different elastic-search versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Is there any way to switch to different elastic-search versions while switching different branch.

I don't want to old version fully just want to switch from one to another version.

My current version is

elasticsearch-1.7.2

I want to upgrade to 5.5

Comment: Have you downloaded it from https://www.elastic.co or from github?

Comment: downloaded elasticsearch-1.7.2 and want to upgrade to 5.5 but while working on this I will have a switch on old version to work on other task

Comment: This is kind of a hack, but I've done it when it was a short-term situation: you can run the new version in docker (while keeping the old version running the same as normal), and use a different port than the default, and in the branch pointing to 5.5, configure to use the correct port.

Comment: I am new to elastic search can you elaborate it also mention the commands